# Mysql case insensitive table names

Tags: mysql, case-insensitive

I had two database, one on windows server, and one on linux server,  I moved the database to the linux server, but I faced wit a problem, On windows when a made a selection foe example

```
SELECT * FROM tabledata
```

Worked fine.

but linux it's not working, because the original table names is `tableData`

Is there any way to configuration the mysql to case-insensitive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A prime example of screwed up cross-plattform design. From the [MySQL documentation on this point](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html):

> the case sensitivity of the underlying
>   operating system plays a part in the
>   case sensitivity of database and table
>   names. This means database and table
>   names are not case sensitive in
>   Windows, and case sensitive in most
>   varieties of Unix.

Fortunately, there is the [lower_case_table_names configuration directive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names), which, when set to 2, would disable case sensitivity for comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just rename the table?

```
ALTER TABLE tableData RENAME TO tabledata;
```

Comment: Ok, But I have more than 100 tables.

Comment: Oh, fun... Perhaps write a quick script to do that for all tables?  Probably a 30-minute job, depending on what scripting language you use.  Or you might be able to stop the mysql server, rename the underlying tables, and start it again.  I know that used to work for MyISAM tables; I'm not sure if that's possible with InnoDB.